# Maximal and Minimal elements of set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

Consider the weak partial order,

$P = (\{\{1\},\{2\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,4\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\}\}, \subset)$

a.) Find the maximal elements in P

b.) Find the minimal elements in P

**Answer:**

a.) The maximal elements in P are $\{1,2\},\{1,3,4\},$ and $\{2,3,4\}$

b.) The minimal elements in P are $\{1\},\{2\},$ and $\{4\}$

**My Question:**

How did they derive those specific values to be maximal and minimal? And why are there 3 in each?

Comment: What is weak partial order

Comment: Do you just mean the partial order given by inclusion?  But, if so, isn't $\{1,2\}$ a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$?  I can see where $\{1,4\}$ is maximal, since it is not a proper subset of anything in $P$.  But not $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Also:  $\{1,3,4\}$ isn't even an element in $P$, the way you have written $P$.  Are you sure you typed correctly?

Comment: @ lulu Apologies, yes that is a type. Fixing now. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: As for "why are there 3 in each?"  That is merely a fluke and just so happened to be the case given the example provided.  Unlike totally ordered sets which can have at most one maximum or minimum (*if one even exists in the first place*), here partially ordered sets can have multiple.  All that an element needs to be considered a maximum is to have no other element "*larger*" than it (*larger in the sense of according to the order itself*).

Comment: If you were to draw yourself a picture of what is going on, for example using an [upward planar drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upward_planar_drawing) of a [Hasse Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram), the minimal elements are the ones who don't have arrows pointing to them while the maximal elements are the ones who don't have any arrows pointing from them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your comment. But why is $\{1,2\}$ one of the maximal but $\{1,4\}$ is not? Isn't $\{1,4\}$ bigger then $\{1,2\}$.? Yikes downvoted already, was this not a good question?

Comment: No, $\{1,4\}$ is not "*bigger than*" $\{1,2\}$.  If you think it is "bigger" somehow, you are using the wrong meaning of "bigger" here.  In the context of this problem, to be "bigger" than means to be a superset of.  $\{1,4\}$ is *not* a superset of $\{1,2\}$, in other words $\{1,2\}$ is not a subset of $\{1,4\}$, and in general for problems like this to be "bigger than" is defined according to what the partial order in question is.

Comment: As for why $\{1,4\}$ is not itself a maximum... that is because $\{1,4\}\subset \{1,3,4\}$ so there is something "bigger" than $\{1,4\}$.  I must emphasize that here according to this order being used, it is not necessary that the maximal elements necessarily have the largest numbers, or the most numbers, or the largest sums of numbers, or any other usual idea of "biggest"  that you might have been thinking of.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah I totally understand now!! Thank you so much for your comments! Really appreciate it.